# Dataframe:cartesian product across columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cartesian-product

I have the following data frame:

```
0   ['1','2,'3']     ['5','6','2']    ['2','5']
1   ['2','3']        ['2','3']        ['1']
```

I want to find the Cartesian product of col1 ,col2 and col3.
Could someone please help. The no of columns in the data frame is generated at runtime.
a[0][0] * a[0][1] * a[0][2]
a[0][0] * a[0][1]  *a[1][2]
etc
Expected output after intersect operation:
2
set()
2
set()
2
set()
2
set()

Comment: I think how looks exactly output DataFrame with numbers

Comment: i didnt get you

Comment: I try explain - I see dataframe with 3 columns, need cartesian product. Output is some new DataFrame, how it looks? It is necessary for verify possible solutions.

Comment: exactly. could you pls explain how you would do it?

Comment: You need count it manually and then create new dataframe

Comment: There is no other way you can automate this?

Comment: It seems not understand each other.

Comment: I wonder who stored these lists in a dataframe in the first place. This is kind of abusing Pandas for something it is not made for. I guess you should present your task from the very beginning ...

Comment: Well, I can explain the whole problem.

Comment: I have the following data:

Comment: a20                                           f20                a0
[5037,5038,5041,5040]          [5037]            [5037]                                                  [5011,5006,5037]                                         [5037]                                                 
[5011,5006,5037]                                          [5037]

Comment: @amdex the result is going to be: 5037,5037,5037,null,null,null,null,null,null,5037,5037,5037,null,null,null,null,null,null,5037.5037,5037,null,null,null,null,null,null

Comment: Pls anyone share your thoughts